# how to select element or delete output string

Tags: jq

I have a json contents

```
 "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "2272dba0-9ffb-49d4-88b7-0a18f38a3cdc",
    "name" : "All_Internet",
    },
    {
    "uid" : "b83fd31c-3cb3-406e-b46b-816a138e8ea1",
    "name" : "Public FTP",
  } ]
```

I used :

```
jq '.objects[] | .name
```

and got the resule:

```
"All_Internet"
"Public FTP"
```

how to select the secondary "name" string, or removing the first "name" "All_Internet" of output

the "All_Internet" is fixed string.

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want an answer like @KiranKandel's, namely:

```
.objects[].name | select(. != "All_Internet")
```

or something like:

```
.objects[1:][].name
```